# How to control which programs are viewable & accessible via Terminal Services?

Tags: configuration, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I know I can control access to programs in Terminal Services (TS) via 'Software Restriction Policies.' But is there a way to show only the programs relevant (i.e. accessible) to the TS user -- something akin to multiple profiles in a regular XP/Vista workstation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Application Virtualization for Terminal Services](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/appv/terminalsvcs.mspx)  this may be closer to what you're trying to achieve.  It's a feature of windows server 2008.

In 2003 you'll have to look at putting in group policy to lock down the terminal services user profile, [loop-back processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260370) & [mandatory profiles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307800) can help with this.

Your other alternative is Citrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - to echo and elaborate on @Nick's answer. Mandatory profiles can do this, but they're a pain to maintain once the environment changes. Look up the Flex Profile Kit - it's a combination of existing free MS technologies that lets you do, essentially, roaming mandatory profiles with customization, and some parts are persistent.

edit - oh snap. It looks like the latest release of the Flex Profile Kit is now non-free. Bastards.